# Как скачать файл по URL на C# Core?

Tags: c#, link, .net-core

Есть список с ссылками, на скачивание файлов (к примеру, https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/nvdcve-2.0-2002.xml.zip). Мне нужно скачать все файлы из этого списка в определённую папку. Как это сделать на C# Core?
Полагаю, что нужно использовать HttpClient() вместо, ранее используемого, WebClient().

На старых версиях C# можно было выполнить так:

```
var сlient = new WebClient();
string path = "some/path/to/download";
webClient.DownloadFile("https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/nvdcve-2.0-2002.xml.zip", path);
```

Как выполнить скачивание в C# Core? Он не поддерживает класс WebClient().

Comment: Приведите пример,  как вы пытаетесь это сделать и в чем конкретно у вас возникает проблема!

Comment: @Yury Bakharev спасибо, я уже решил проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил данный вопрос:

```
public static async void DownloadFile(string url, string path)
{
    byte[] data;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        data = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        using (FileStream file = File.Create(path)) //path = "wwwroot\\XML\\1.zip"
            file.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Async void предназначен только для событий. В вашем случае ожидать вызывающему нечего (void) поскольку нет объекта Task.

Comment: @VladislavKhapin, всё верно говорите, но мне нужно было хотя бы сделать, чтобы файлы скачивались. У меня получилось скачать файлы и я сразу же привёл пример, а если кому-то будет полезен мой пример, полагаю, что они смогут доделать и обработку исключений, и возвращать то, что им нужно